# Applying sorting to LINQ query using LINQKit

Tags: linqkit, ef-core-6.0

So I have this multilingual datamodel: Product -> ProductTranslation

- `Product` has an `Id` property.
- `ProductTranslation` has a `Culture` (e.g. 'nl') and a `Name` property.

I already have a working query that flattens a product for a specific language to a ProductModel (using Automapper).

- `ProductModel` has an `Id` and a `Name` property.

`ProductModel.Name` contains the `Name` from the appropriate `ProductTranslation`, which I determine in the query by comparing the client application culture to `ProductTranslation.Culture`.

So far all good and no LINQKit involved.

Now I'd like to sort the products returned by `ProductTranslation.Name`. My question is if this can be using LINQKit. I do want to do the sorting on the database side, so materializing and doing it on the client side is no option (left out paging to simplify the example here).

I do have an expression already that will determine the correct translation:

```cs
Expression<Func<ICollection<ProductTranslation>, ProductTranslation>> expression =
            translations => translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Culture.Equals(cultureName))
                 ?? translations.FirstOrDefault();
```

Can I somehow expand on this to get the `Name` property from the `ProductTranslation` this returns and apply it as a sorting expression?

Thanks in advance, cheers!

Comment: Can you show us the query you want to sort?

Comment: @NetMage Changed the name for clarity.

Comment: LINQKit certainly handles string-based `OrderBy` though I fail to see what that gains you here - you apparently already know the field is `ProductModel.Name`

Answer (score 0):

After some more investigating this seems to work fine:

```
var cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
var languageName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

return s => s.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Culture == cultureName).Name ??
            s.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Culture == languageName).Name ??
            s.FirstOrDefault().Name;
```

Unfortunately this only resolves part of my problem. The issue left is, that I'd like to be able to specify the property (in this case `Name`) using another lambda expression of type `Expression<Func<ProductTranslation>, object>`, which I can pass to the method that creates the expression.

So in that method I end up with two expression that I need to combine. It boils down to this:

```
public static Expression<Func<Product, object>> FromTranslation
{
    get
    {
        var cultureName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.Name;
        var languageName = Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture.TwoLetterISOLanguageName;

        Expression<Func<Product, ProductTranslation>> translationExpression = s =>
            s.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Culture == cultureName) ??
            s.Translations.FirstOrDefault(t => t.Culture == languageName) ??
            s.Translations.FirstOrDefault();

        Expression<Func<ProductTranslation, object>> memberExpression = t => t.Name;

        // TODO: Combine expressions somehow?
        return ??;
    }
}
```

Can I somehow extend the `translationExpression` with the `memberExpression`, so I end up with one expression?